# Value of the last element of a list

Tags: list, f#, reverse, tail

how to get the value of the last element of a List? I've noted that List.hd (or .Head) return an item, while List.tl (or .Tail) returns a List.

Is rev the List and get the hd the only way around? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this function. It uses recursion, though it gets optimised to iteration anyway since it's tail recursion. In any case, it is most likely quicker than reversing the entire list (using `List.rev`).

```
let rec last = function
    | hd :: [] -> hd
    | hd :: tl -> last tl
    | _ -> failwith "Empty list."
```

The answer of Pavel Minaev is definitely worth taking into account, however. Nonetheless, the algorithm you have requested may be useful in some rare cases, and is the most efficient way to go about the task.

Comment: Since this is a tail recursive algorithm, the compiler will implement it as an efficient while loop. I tend to agree with Pavel regarding choice of data structure, but if you need to use a list then this is the right approach.

Comment: @dahlbyk: Exactly. I meant to make a note about that, but it looks like I forgot - I shall add it now.

Comment: it must be "let rec last tl = function", function last has no parameter

Answer (score 27):

In general, if you need to do this, you're doing something wrong. Since F# lists are single-linked, accessing the last element is costly - `O(N)`, where N is size of `list`. Try to rewrite your algorithm so that you always access the *first* element, not the last (which is `O(1)`). If you cannot do so, chances are good that your choice of `list` for a data structure wasn't correct in the first place.

Answer (score 12):

A quick & dirty way of doing it is by using List.reduce. Assuming the list is called `ls`,

```
let lastElement ls = List.reduce (fun _ i -> i) ls
```

As for efficiency, I agree with Pavel.

Answer (score 5):

A more concise version based on Mitch's answer:

```
let lastItem = myList |> List.rev |> List.head
```

The `myList` list is sent to `List.rev` function. The result is then processed by `List.head`

Answer (score 3):

Agreed, not so efficient to get the last element of `list`, or any other "enumerable" sequence. That said, this function already exists in the `Seq` module, `Seq.last`.

Comment: And even if it didn't, it's easily defined: `module Seq = let last xs = Seq.reduce (fun _ x -> x) xs`

Answer (score 1):

As a novice F# developer, I don't see what the harm is in doing the following

```
let mylist = [1;2;3;4;5]

let lastValue = mylist.[mylist.Length - 1]
```

Imperative in nature? Yes but no need for recursion.

Comment: This will take a reasonably long time as `List.length` requires traversing the list, as does the access.  Essentially you have to traverse the list twice.

Comment: I just checked the source code, you are correct. Why a property computers this value however, is beyond me. Perhaps I expected lists to have the same behavior as arrays when knowing about the number of elements.

Comment: Lists don't cache their size - this reduces their size in memory significantly, as you need to cache the size at every element.

Comment: By size do you mean length? I was under the impression that a list has an array as a backing store which creates a new array and copies the elements across when the size exceeds its capacity.

Comment: The lists with an array as a backing store are `System.Collections.Generic.List<_>`, these are not the same as the F# lists, and have different performance goals.

Answer (score 0):

The regular way to work with lists in F# is to use recursion. The first item in a list is the head (obviously) and the rest of the list is the tail (as oppose to the last item). So when a function recieves a list it processes the *head* and then recursively processes the rest of the list (the *tail*).

```
let reversedList = List.rev originalList
let tailItem = List.hd reversedList
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just write

```
list.[0..list.Length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call List.Head to get the first element of a list, such that the below expression evaluates to true:

```
let lst = [1;2;3;4;5]
List.head lst = 1
```

However, calling List.Tail will return every element in the list *after* the first element, such that the below expression is true:

```
let lst = [1;2;3;4;5]
List.tail lst = [2;3;4;5]
```

Like some other people have mentioned, there isn't an efficient way in F# to get the tail end of a list, basic lists just aren't built with that functionality in mind. If you really want to get the last element you're going to have to reverse your list first, and then take the new head (which was the previous tail).

```
let lst = [1;2;3;4;5]
(List.head (List.rev lst) ) = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked fine with me, I've an array of integers, want to start from the 5th item, then take it minus the item number

```
Sum of [Array(xi) - Array(xi-5)] where i start at 5
```

The code used is:

```
series |> Array.windowed 5
       |> Array.fold (fun s x -> 
                            (x |> Array.rev |> Array.head) -  (x |> Array.head) + s) 0
       |> float
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old question, but just in case someone comes here:

with FSharp 5, you can do x.[^index] where index will start at the end of the array / list.

```
let a = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]

a.[^0] is 9
a.[^1] is 8
etc
```

Comment: That's a nice feature, but I also wonder if this too traverses the list twice. That doesn't mean this feature is bad of course, but perhaps not optimal for retrieving the last element.

Comment: Unless the store the list length; I haven’t looked at the implementation but it’s definitely a valid concern