# F#, why can't I access the "Item" member

Tags: arrays, f#

In F#, why can't I access the "Item" member on the Array here:

```
let last (arr:System.Array) =
    let leng = arr.Length
    arr.[leng-1]   // Error: Field, constructor or member "Item" is not defined.
```

Comment: `System.Array` doesn't have an `Item` member, you need to use `GetValue(int)` instead. You probably don't want to use `System.Array` directly however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
let last (arr:_[]) =
       let leng = arr.Length
       arr.[leng-1]
```

Comment: because [] is not a System.Array but inherits from it? What is []?

Comment: @Goswin You can think of `System.Array` as the abstract base class of all concrete array types, such as `int[]`. Important is the absence of a type parameter. How should the compiler know what kind of elements your array contains. `Object` as the base type of all types is not a good answer as type safety could not be guaranteed statically. Wei Ma's answer defines a generic function. That way you can deal in terms of a concrete array type. `_[]` uses wildcard syntax to get around defining a type parameter. `'a[]` would be equivalent. It is an "array of 'a", which is a subtype of `System.Array`

Comment: @ChristianKlauser @Lee Where can I look up what `[]` is? where can I look up that `[]` has a member called `Item` ? Is it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370273.aspx?) ?

Comment: @Goswin so this last link you mention is about the *module* called Array. I know, it only gets better ;). There is some lesson to take away here though : modules are where you put most (all?) of your functions in the functional approach, which is : one **datastructure**, as 'type explicit' as possible , and a list of **functions** grouped in modules. for instance, you have the Seq module, and the sequence (=IEnumerable) structure, the Async module and the async builder, etc, etc...

Comment: Other equivalent syntaxes for the generic array type annotation: `array<_>`, `array<'a>`, `_ array`, `'a array`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a general dotnet thing. Looking up the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) I see

> The Array class is the base class for language implementations that
>   support arrays. However, only the system and compilers can derive
>   explicitly from the Array class. Users should employ the array
>   constructs provided by the language.

Comment: I got confused by the documentation where it says: The type of all [F# arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx)  **is** [the .NET Framework type Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx). Therefore, F# arrays support all the functionality available in Array.

Answer (score 1):

Also, note that in F# you'd typically use an immutable List:

```
let last (stuff: _ list) =
    let l = stuff.Length
    stuff.[l]
```

But if you're using a list, you'd use a [more efficient algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175056/value-of-the-last-element-of-a-list); F# lists are linked lists:

```
let rec last = function
    | hd :: [] -> hd
    | hd :: tl -> last tl
    | _ -> failwith "Empty list."
```

Comment: `stuff.Length` and `stuff.[l]` are both O(N) operations -- neither should be used in idiomatic F# code.

Comment: Ok, I'll improve this answer.