# F# - What is array<'T>?

Tags: arrays, f#, definition

In this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968060/f-why-cant-i-access-the-item-member) I learnt that in F# an `array<'T>` is not the same as `System.Array`.

VS tells me that `array<'T>` inherits `System.Array` and has the full name `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.array<_>` and some additional Interfaces.

However [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353605.aspx) says that `array<'T>` is a type abbreviation of `System.Array`.  And that it has the notation `arr.[i]` to get and set items.

So for my lesson, is `array<'T>` a type abbreviation that includes type extensions and additional Interfaces? Where is the best place to look this up ?

Comment: See also this thread https://twitter.com/_cartermp/status/1509946503682396162

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type `array<'T>` is an abbreviation, but not for the base type `System.Array` but for another generic type that represents arrays in F#, which is written as `'T[]`.

This means that

- `System.Array` is the non-generic base type (where you cannot use indexing and you can only get elements as objects)
- `'T[]` and `array<'T>` mean exactly the same thing. They are the generic type which supports indexing and you get `'T` values from it.

Comment: Also note that the generic types can be written before the type and without angle braces, so you can write, say, `string array` which reads very nice; much nicer than `array<string>` or `string[]`.

Comment: how can I make type extensions on `[]`? `type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array with
    member arr.last with get() = arr.[arr.Length -1]` does not work for me

Comment: for type extension see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359825/f-how-to-extended-the-generic-array-type