# F# how to extended the generic array type?

Tags: f#, type-extension

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981185/f-what-is-arrayt) I wonder how (or if) i can extend the generic F# Array Type.
I could do this:

```
type System.Array with
    member a.Last = a.GetValue(a.Length - 1)
```

but as Tomas mentioned it is non generic. Next I tried this but it does not work:

```
type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array with  // Error: Array is not defined      
    member a.Last = a.[a.Length - 1]
```

In the F# scource I found this namespace, but it does not work either:

```
type Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array with  // Error: Array is not defined          
    member a.Last = a.[a.Length - 1]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bit confusing - but I was recently looking for something in the F# specification and came across this:

```
type 'T ``[]`` with
    member a.Last = a.[a.Length - 1]

[| 1 .. 10 |].Last
```

The double-backtick encoding is normally used to turn reserved keywords into valid F# identifiers (e.g. if you want to have a property that has a space in the name, or is named `let`). Here, it probably means that the compiler needs to treat `[]` as an ordinary type "name" rather than as a special syntax for arrays.