# F# extend jagged array type

Tags: f#, type-extension

I have read the question [F# how to extended the generic array type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359825/f-how-to-extended-the-generic-array-type) and it's answer, and it's pretty close to what I wan't to do. Is it possible to extend the type `'T[][]`, just like it is with `'T[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jagged array `[][]` is an array`[]` specialized in another array.

You can use `[,]` which is a 2D array:

```
type 'T ``[,]`` with
    member a.First = a.GetValue(0,0)

(array2D [| [| 1 .. 10 |] ; [| 11 .. 20 |] |] ).First
```

But if you really want to use `[][]` you can't do it with this F# specific notation, it is not possible to declare it specialized since this notation mirrors the Type Definition, so you have to do it the .NET way:

```
[<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]
module Extensions =

    [<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]   
    let First   (x  :_ [][]) = x.[0].[0]
```

It will work when accessed from C#, but from F# I think you will need F# 3.1

Comment: Yes, that's possible to do. But ``'T[][]`` and ``'T[,]`` aren't the same type - or am I missing something here?

Comment: You are right they are not the same, but 'T[][] is a normal array having arrays as elements. So if you want to use it like this, you can extend it the way showed in the answer you linked. If you are trying to specify an extension for a generic type specialized in a specific type I think is not possible using that notation, however you can do it the standard .NET way. but you will need F# 3.1