# What is wrong in F# code?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

In F# I am trying to get last element of give list. I wrote below code

```
let rec findLast t =
    match t with
        | hd :: [] -> hd
        | hd :: tl -> findLast tl
        | _ -> -1

printfn "%A" (findLast [1,2,3,4,5])
```

But when I tried to execute it in F# Interactive it complain as below

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>       int     but here has type
>       'a * 'b * 'c * 'd * 'e

I just want to know what is wrong in above code. I know there are different smart and elegant ways to get last element from list in F#. But I am interested to know what is wrong in above code ?

Comment: List elements are separated by `;` not `,`. Use `findLast [1;2;3;4;5]` or just `findLast [1..5]`

Comment: Here you can find a list of common errors every F# programmer will run into: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/troubleshooting-fsharp/ The tip "Use semicolons for list separators" is also mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1,2,3,4,5` is a tuple. `'a * 'b * 'c * 'd * 'e` is a tuple definition. Create a list with semicolons `[1;2;3;4;5]`. `[1,2,3,4,5]` is a list of tuples with one item which is a quintuple.

```
let rec findLast t =
    match t with
        | hd :: [] -> hd
        | hd :: tl -> findLast tl
        | _ -> -1

printfn "%A" (findLast [1;2;3;4;5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
let rec lastElem = function
    | []    -> None
    | [x]   -> Some x
    | x::xs -> lastElem xs
```

You can try it in the REPL:

```
> lastElem [1;2;3];;

val it : int option = Some 3

> lastElem ["a";"b";"c"];;

val it : string option = Some "c"
```

Comment: Although the code is correct it won't explain why the OP code was wrong ; mostly because with your code his test will work (not with the result he expected though) returning him the only tuple item in his list

Answer (score 1):

As @Phillip-Scott-Givens pointed out, you've likely made a totally common (especially for C#'ers), error and used a comma to separate a list instead of a semi-colon.

This results in a tuple list [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)] and not an integer list [1;2;3;4;5].  Getting unexpected asterisks in your type definitions is a symptom of this :)

That said, here a few different functions that get the last value from your tuple, list, and tuple list (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1175123/5470873):

```ml
// Data: 
let tuples = [ (1,2,3,4,5); ]      // = [1,2,3,4,5]
let firstListElement = tuples.[0]  


// Access: 
let rec lastItemInList = function
    | hd :: [] -> hd
    | hd :: tl -> lastItemInList tl
    | _ -> failwith "Empty list."
let lastValueOfFirstItem = function
    | (_, _, _, _, last) :: _ -> last
    | _ -> -1
let lastValueOfTuple = function _, _, _, _, last -> last
// same as: let lastValueOfTuple myTuple = 
//              match myTuple with
//              | (_, _, _, _, last) -> last


// Examples:
tuples |> lastItemInList              // val it : int * int * int * int * int = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
tuples |> lastValueOfFirstItem        // val it : int = 5
tuples |> List.map lastValueOfTuple   // val it : int list = [5]
firstListElement |> lastValueOfTuple  // val it : int = 5
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing link above.